# get_absolute_url not working in django 1.7?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to navigate to my product page by clicking on the href link under the displayed product. But for some reason, the absolute url that is generated is giving me a 404. This is what i tried so far.
models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                            help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords", max_length=255,
                                     help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255,
                                        help_text='Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'catalog_category', (), {'category_slug': self.slug}


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'



class Product(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True,help_text = 'Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2,blank = True, default = 0.00)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255,help_text = 'Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=255,help_text = 'Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'catalog_product', (), {'product_slug': self.slug}

    def sale_price(self):
        if self.old_price > self.price:
            return self.price
        else:
            return None


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('catalog.views',
                       (r'^index/$', 'index', {'template_name': 'catalog/index.html'}, 'catalog_home'),

                       (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_category',
                        {'template_name': 'catalog/category.html'}, 'catalog_category'),

                       (r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_product',
                        {'template_name': 'catalog/product.html'}, 'catalog_product'),

                       (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                        {'document_root': '/home/surajt/Downloads/ecommerce/static'}),
                       )
```

This is what i see when i did a code inspect in the html.

huggies

Thats how the href url is being generated in the html and this is what i am getting when i click on the url.
127.0.0.1:8000/demo/category/diapers/(u'catalog_product',%20(),%20%7Bu'product_slug':%20u'huggies'%7D)

What could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: Django 1.7 is [very, very far out of support](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions). If you intend to continue supporting/developing your project, you should check the upgrade path to 1.11 (which is currently projected to have support for longer than any current release on the 2.x branch).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your params through `reverse` but then also leave out those empty braces in the middle, a bit like this;

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('catalog_product', kwargs={'product_slug': self.slug})
```

You can see an example here; https://godjango.com/67-understanding-get_absolute_url/